# Changing audio volume in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, volume, librosa

I'm working with audio files in a Jupyter notebook, loading/processing with Librosa and playing audio back with IPython.display.  I can use `np.multiply(audio_file, 0.25)` to change the amplitude of the audio array, but IPython.display's Audio plays it back at exactly the same volume regardless.  The following also does not work to change the playback volume:

```
audio_file_softer = audio_file * 0.25
Audio(audio_file_softer, rate=sr)
```

It seems pyaudio no longer works with Python.  How can I alter the volume of the playback audio?  Any better libraries for playing back audio from within a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: two years later. still hurting folks' ears